# Regex to check for "+=" inside of a method

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Going through our codebase, many of our custom controls have a `DetachEvents` method that gets called with the control is being disposed. Quite frequently, other developers incorrectly are the event handler

```
private void DetachEvents()
{
    myControl.Click += new EventHandler(myControl_Click);
}
```

When it should, of course, be `-=` instead of `+=`.

I'm trying to come up with a regex for the Find & Replace tool in Visual Studios to only find me `DetachEvent` methods that contain the `+=` but I cannot figure out how to. I'll be here all day if I just keep Finding every occurance of `DetachEvents()`

I tried: `DetachEvents()[.]+=[.]` thinking the period would find anything before and after the `+=` but it doesn't find anything.

Comment: Rather than using a regex, have you considered using something like Roslyn to get the relevant abstract syntax tree?

Comment: Don't forget that if you are using Visual Studio with Regexes you are working with a totally weird and nonsensical dialect: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/07/the-visual-studio-ide-and-regular-expressions.html

Comment: @glenatron that's been "fixed" since VS 2012. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't know what Roslyn is, or what a "relevant abstract syntax tree" means.

Comment: Well did you search to find out what either of those things might mean? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree

Comment: Jon is right, this is something perfect for Roslyn to do. A regex will be far inferior.

Comment: Well, write a very small parse to get C#'s method is not too hard.. it would be powerful than regexp and more easy to detect any case of += operator. Basically, get a characer, if it's a letter read it as word(all characters until a white-space) is seen if it's public/private/protected etc go to check for a type name followed it and if so, check if next character is the '(' token and then call your function to look for word followed by += symbol otherwise skip over such a token and get next. That's basically that. I don't know how more complex is this solution than Jon Skeet's one.

Comment: @TheMask Roslyn does that for you. That's its purpose. All you need to do is look at the actual parsed data.

Comment: @vcsjones thanks, I didn't realise that. Only been using 2012 for a little few weeks so I haven't got used to it yet. Still spending half my time trying to figure out what the new tiny monochrome icons mean.

Comment: @JonSkeet Well, doesn't seem to available for older versions of VS-- I'm using 2010. I found this link on Nuget to an older version, downloaded it from the package manager console but I don't really know how to install it or anything...

Answer (score 3):

Try escaping the `+`:

```
DetachEvents().*\+=
```

But this will match any instance of `+=` which follows `DetatchEvents()`. You might want to use `[^}]` instead of `.`, assuming you don't have any other code blocks inside the `DetachEvents` method:

```
DetachEvents()[^}]*\+=
```

Comment: That first one doesn't seem to find anything, and the second one errors out saying `Empty character set [] or [^] was specified.` :(

Tried removing the curly brace and it doesn't give me an error, but also doesn't return anything.

Comment: @sab669 What if you try escaping the `}`, like this `DetachEvents()[^\}]*\+=`

Comment: @gleng pale, skinny white guy.

Comment: @p.s.w.g +1 For actually answering that. I've always wondered when I see your name!

Comment: As an addendum: if your `DetachEvents` methods can have an arbitrary number of code blocks in them before the `+=`, regular expressions are no longer powerful enough to match what you want, unless you can figure out a regex that can match method or property definitions (but not method calls), and do a negative match on those.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, @Eric Finn. I was hoping there was just some "generic enough" check I could add inbetwen DetachEvents and the +=

Comment: @sab669 That's why Jon Skeet suggested dealing with abstract syntax trees rather than plain text in his comment on your question.

Comment: @sab669 However, if you limit code blocks to a certain level of nesting `n`, you could construct a regular expression that will work. It just won't be able to match what you're looking for if there are `n+1` levels of nesting.