# How to extract an unknown amount of text from a file

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

This sort of ties back to a [question I had earlier about a regex to search for a method containing a particular string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20501839/regex-to-check-for-inside-of-a-method), and someone suggested I use this MS tool called Roslyn but it's not available for VS2010 since 2012 came out.

So I'm writing this small utility to keep a list of every file in my solution that contains a particular method declaration (something like 3k of the 25k files overload this method). Then I simply want to filter that list of files to only ones that contain `+=` inside the body of the method.

```
static void DirSearch(string dir)
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        var contents = File.ReadAllText(file);
        if (contents.Contains("void DetachEvents()"))
        {
            //IF DetachEvents CONTAINS += THEN...
                WriteToFile(file);
        }                
     }
}
```

This method iterates over all the folders and writes the file name to a text file if it contains the key method, but I have no idea how to extract just whatevers in the method body, since it's overloaded all 3K instances of the method are different.

Would the best approach to be get the index of the method name, then the index of each `{` and `}` until I encounter the next accessor modifier (signifying I've gotten to the end of `DetachEvents`)? Then I could just search between `indexOfMethod` and `indexOfEndMethod` for `+=`.

But it sounds really sloppy, I was hoping someone might have a better idea?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey I'm not sure what you mean. I don't intend to have my tool modify any of the code, simply tell me which ones have a mistake. So, it's only reading their contents, and writing the file name to a local file if they have flagrant data, for me to go back and manually change. I don't expect an alarming number of wrong data, but I don't want to manually check 3K files ;)

Comment: Do you really have 3,000 different overloads of the same method in your code base?

Comment: @acfrancis Quickly running the code here in my post without any "filtering" yields a textfile with some 2.9k entries or so. They're not actually overloading a method from one common interface, but they just have the same method signature(`private void DetachEvents()`) where it goes and, as the name implies, detaches events from each control on it. Not quite the same as overloading, but close enough that I just called it that for simplicity's sake.

Comment: Right, well I guess you could read the file from the method signature counting open and closing curlies until they balance out (that's probably the end of the method), looking for the ``+=`` at the same time. It won't be exact because you might count things in strings or comments but it should be pretty close.

Comment: Can the += be anywhere in the body of the method or can you narrow the bit of syntax that you are looking for a bit more?

Comment: It could be anywhere. Each `DetachEvents()` method has an undeterminable number of events it's detaching from the specific class. Some might have one, some might have 10, or even more. Basically while copy-pasting from the constructor where they were assigning event handlers **to** the controls, my teammates forgot to change the `+=` to `-=` for the removal. Most of the times they didn't, but while looking at a class today I noticed one event wasn't changed. Looked over 20 other files and they ranged from one or two events not being changed, to the entire body being incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this really sloppy winform that lets the user type in the folder to the code base, the method name, and the flagrant text they're looking for. Then it loops over every file in the directory and calls this method on a string that contains all the text of the file. It returns `true` if the user-entered flagrant data is present, then the method that calls this adds the file its on to a list. Anyways, here's the major code:

```
    private bool ContainsFlag(string contents)
    {
        int indexOfMethodDec = contents.IndexOf(_method);
        int indexOfNextPublicMethod = contents.IndexOf("public", indexOfMethodDec);
        if (indexOfNextPublicMethod == -1)
            indexOfNextPublicMethod = int.MaxValue;

        int indexOfNextPrivateMethod = contents.IndexOf("private", indexOfMethodDec);
        if (indexOfNextPrivateMethod == -1)
            indexOfNextPrivateMethod = int.MaxValue;

        int indexOfNextProtectedMethod = contents.IndexOf("protected", indexOfMethodDec);
        if (indexOfNextProtectedMethod == -1)
            indexOfNextProtectedMethod = int.MaxValue;

        int[] indeces = new int[3]{indexOfNextPrivateMethod,
                                   indexOfNextProtectedMethod,
                                   indexOfNextPublicMethod};

        int closestToMethod = indeces.Min();
        if (closestToMethod.Equals(Int32.MaxValue))
            return false; //This should probably do something different.. This condition is true if the method you're reading is the last method in the class, basically

       if (closestToMethod - indexOfMethodDec < 0)
            return false;

        string methodBody = contents.Substring(indexOfMethodDec, closestToMethod - indexOfMethodDec);
        if (methodBody.Contains(_flag))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

**Plenty** of room for improvement, this is mostly just a proof-of-concept thing that'll get used maybe twice per year internally. But for my purposes it worked. Should be a good starting-point for something more sophisticated if anyone needs it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to do this in code?  Is this a one time utility to identify the problem methods?  Why not use something like `Notepad++` and it's `Find in Files` capabilities.  You can filter your find pretty easily and even apply regex (I think).  From there you can copy the results which include the file name (i.e. `someclassfile.cs`) and get a list from there.

Comment: You are correct in that this is a one-time use tool. Well, I suppose in the future people will probably wrongly assign `+=` instead of `-=` but, what can I do about that. I tried using the regex search built into Visual Studios to search my whole solution for a few different things (see the SO question I linked at the top of my post) and a few other people weighed in saying it'd be mighty difficult to create a Regex that'd find every instance of the problem, because each method removes a varying number of event handlers.

Also, I can't imagine trying to open 28K files in N++ to search through.

Comment: Comment length limiter!! I'm open to any solution, so if you know of a way I could easily parse a list of these improper method bodies using N++'s search I'm all ears